# Let function use local variable made in another function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing a project for my school work and I having some troubles. I am trying to allow a function to use a variable created in another function.
This is what I have tried so far in simple terms:

1)

```
def randomQuestions(self):
   x = 9*5
   y = 7*4

   return x
   return z

def create_question_widgets(self):
   print(x)
   print(z)
```

2)

```
def randomQuestions(self):
   x = 9*5
   z = 7*4

   self.create_question_widgets(self,x,z)

def create_question_widgets(self,x,z):
   print(x)
   print(z)
```

I am a new/bad coder so please bear with my bad code. I have also Googled what to do but it didn't help me a lot. Thanks.

Comment: When functions are part of a class, it is important your provide the class definition as well as it is an important part of your code

Comment: Thank you Oliver, I will be aware of this next time I possibly ask a question related with Classes

Comment: Nonetheless, I could guess you were using a class. I suggest you edit your question for clarity, but you can have a look at the already provided answers that ccounted for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Errors

The error in your first attempt is that you have two `return` statements. Once a function returns, it will stop. Although it is possible to return multiple values as a `tuple`.

```
return x, y
```

The error in your second attempt is that you do not need to provide `self` as argument to a bound isntance method. It is passed implicitly.

```
self.create_question_widgets(x, z)
```

### Solution

Although, tt seems those are methods from some class. This means you could store `x` and `y` as instance attributes.

```
class Foo:
    def randomQuestions(self):
        self.x = 9 * 5
        self.y = 7 * 4

    def create_question_widgets(self):
        print(self.x)
        print(self.y)

foo = Foo()
foo.randomQuestions()
foo.create_question_widgets()
```

### Output

```
45
28
```

Comment: To be exact `return x, y` doesn't return two values. It returns one tuple that contains two values.

Answer (score 1):

If you make x and y instance attributes,  like this:

```
self.x = 9*5
self.y = 7*4
```

then you don't need the return statements (can't have two in one method like that anyway) and in the next method:

```
def create_question_widgets(self):
   print(self.x)
   print(self.z)
```